How to detect Bluetooth headset disconnection in a web application on Chrome for Android?
I'm developing a web application that plays audio or video content. I want to detect when a user disconnects their Bluetooth headset (e.g., takes off their Bluetooth headphones) while using the application, so I can automatically pause or stop the media playback.
I've tried several methods to achieve this, but none have worked so far:

Listening to Media Element Events:
I added event listeners for pause, ended, stalled, waiting, and error events on the  or  element. However, none of these events fire when the Bluetooth headset is disconnected on Chrome for Android.

mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', handlePause);
mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', handleEnded);
mediaElement.addEventListener('stalled', handleStalled);
mediaElement.addEventListener('waiting', handleWaiting);
mediaElement.addEventListener('error', handleError);


Using navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange: I attempted to use the navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange event to detect changes in connected devices. However, this event is not available on Chrome for Android.

Web Bluetooth API: I considered using the Web Bluetooth API to detect when the Bluetooth headset disconnects. Unfortunately, the API is designed for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices and doesn't support classic Bluetooth audio devices like headsets.


Interesting Observation:
I noticed that when I watch videos on YouTube in Chrome for Android and disconnect my Bluetooth headset, the video pauses automatically. This suggests that it's possible to detect the disconnection of a Bluetooth audio device in a web application.
Question:
How can I detect the disconnection of a Bluetooth headset in a web application using JavaScript, so that I can pause or stop media playback when this happens? Are there any APIs or workarounds that can help achieve this functionality, particularly on Chrome for Android?
Additional Information:

I'm targeting mobile users who may switch between audio output devices.
The solution needs to work specifically on Chrome for Android.
I understand that there might be security and privacy limitations in browsers.

